What does it mean for a functor to be adjoint to the identity of another functor?
In "Transformation Groups and Algebraic K-Theory" by Wolfgang Lück he talks about the functor $J_{X}M:E_{X}\circ Res_{X}M\rightarrow M$, where $E_{X}:$MOD-$R[X]\rightarrow $MOD-$R\Gamma$ is the extension functor sending $M$ to $M\otimes_{R[X]}RHom(-,X) $, being adjoint of the identity of the restriction functor $Res_{X}:$MOD-$R\Gamma\rightarrow$MOD-$R[X]$ sending $M$ to $M(X)$. Can anyone explain what this means? (9.36 for context).

The context would be much improved if you shared an image, or better still, explained the concepts yourself.

I will update the question to define what is meant by these functors, however, I am interested in understanding what is meant by this in the general context of functors. I don't presently have access to a scanner.

@Rhoswyn What is meant here depends on what these functors are, their domains and codomains, etc. For a start, the categorial notion of "adjoint" generally has to be qualified as "left" or "right," so perhaps that's not what's meant here? Also, you shouldn't need a scanner: We don't generally accept questions that rely on images when they could just as well rely on text, for searchability and accessibility reasons.

The answer by John shows quite impressively that the full context is always important to add. OP's often mix things up (without knowing, of course).

Note that you are misreading a few things:

$J_{x}M : E_{x} \circ \mathrm{RES}_{x} M \to M$ is not a functor, but an $R\Gamma$-homomorphism.
$\mathrm{RES}_{x}M$ is not a functor, but an $R[x]$-module.

So the claim in the text is that the $R\Gamma$-homomorphism $J_{x}M$ is the adjoint of the identity $R[x]$-homomorphism of $\mathrm{RES}_{x}M$.
What is going on in general is the following.  We have categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ and functors $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$.  If these functors are adjoint, then there is a bijection
$$
  \mathcal{D}(Fc, d)
  =
  \mathcal{C}(c, Gd)
$$
natural in $c$ and $d$, by definition of adjoint functors.  Any arrow $f : c \to Gd$ in $\mathcal{C}$ corresponds to a unique arrow $f^{\dagger} : Fc \to d$ in $\mathcal{C}$; the arrow $f^{\dagger}$ is called the adjoint of $f$.  In particular, the identity arrow $\mathrm{id}_{Gd} : Gd \to Gd$ has an adjoint $\mathrm{id}_{Gd}^{\dagger} : FGd \to d$.  The text is concerned with the case in which $F = E_{x}$ and $G = \mathrm{RES}_{x}$ and $d = M$.
